# How to solve the 1292 error code in Django+MySQL in production?

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

My Django project works with a MySQL database. It runs well on my local machine without any sort of problems. Now, I am trying to release it in production, but my date columns are not accepting the same values which were accepted on the local machine. The returned error is shown below:

> django "(1292, "1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2023-07-23 09:41:00+00:00' for column 'date' at row 1", '22007')"

I am using a Linux server in production and a cPanel dashboard while my local machine is Windows.

I have no clue what I can do to resolve the problem and there is not much relative content on the internet about it that I could find.

Comment: What is MySQL version on both machines?

Comment: my local machine runs with version 8 &
my host I believe is running with version 5.2

Comment: 5.2 is very old version (5.5 was released 12 years ago). and Many things that work with 8 wouldn't work with 5.2. So if you are stuck with it then I recommend to you downgrade your PC version and look for a proper guide.

Comment: It's true.  MySQL 5 does not support timezones in date/time literals.  Do you need the timezone support, or can you strip the timezone string and assume local time?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: Yes, thank you guys. The issue is with MySQL version. I must upgrade my host configurations.